# Can't understand some codes in redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I'm using some example codes from redux-form document, and I have some codes that I don't understand in renderField function.

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <div>
        <input className="form-control" {...input} type={type}/>
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

I don't understand code below

`{touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}`

If touched is true... and what? I know the result, but don't know process...

Comment: If touched and error exist, evaluate to `<span>{error}</span>`. Basically show a span containing the error if touch and error exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing to do with React really, it's how javascript evaluates expressions.

Here is the [relevant docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FExpressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators)

```
expr1 && expr2
```

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both
>   operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

Since the expressions are not boolean, and cannot be converted to false (such as `null` or `undefined`), it will return the last value, which in this case a `span` with the error in it

And, as Mayank answer mention, JSX only allows expressions. `if` is considered as statement, not expression, hence not allowed within JSX. So you will see react devs using other features of javascript to get back that control.

Answer (score 0):

If you break the above code using `if else` and `ternary` operator, it will look like this:

```
1.   if(touched && error)
        <span>{error}</span>

2. if(touched)
      if(error)
         <span>{error}</span>

3. {touched && error ? <span>{error}</span> : null}
```

It simply means that if `touched and error both are true then only render this span`.

**Note**: `if` is not allowed to use inside `JSX`, i used it to make a clear picture. If you want to use `if` then call a function from render method and inside that you can use 1 and 2 way to return the span.